# Square root algorithm

Tags: python

I was working with coding test web site,
there's something I don't understand

```
import math

def solution(n):
    return pow(math.sqrt(n)+1,2) if (pow(math.sqrt(n),2) == n) else -1
```

the result of the test was 87% correct.
and I found out I shouldn't use `if(pow(math.sqrt(n),2) == n)` but `if(math.sqrt(n)% 1 == 0)` is okay.

why not the first one?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is a bit confused. It's nearly impossible to understand what are you looking for. We cannot know what your goal is and why your tests are failing. Please add more details

Comment: What is the purpose of this code?

Comment: If you mean to test whether the number is a square by `pow(math.sqrt(n), 2) == n`, it's not reliable due to the loss of precision. For example, it will return `True` for `n = 99`.

Comment: @bereal due to precision the outcome is `False` for a lot of values of `n`. It works for `n=99`.

Comment: @TCMolenaar yes, it works for many values of `n`. It _doesn't_ work like the OP expected for any sufficiently large number which is sufficiently close to a perfect square (returns a false positive).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the output, the problem lies in comparing float values.
Here Python might compare something like 2.99999999... and 3 that is not considered the same.
Maybe try to convert to int before comparing the values.

For the second verification case though, x % 1 is always 0 if x is Integer.